# Exponentially decaying interpolation

Tags: pandas, scipy, interpolation

I am not sure if I used the correct technical words in the title. What I want is something like the following.

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, None, None, 4, None, None, None, 10]])
df = df.fillna(np.nan)
df = df.transpose().interpolate()
```

which does a linear interpolation, which gives me something like

```
  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.5  7.0  8.5  10.0
```

What I want is an exponentially decaying interpolation. That is, something like below (Not the exact values but you get the idea).

```
  1.0  2.5  3.0  4.0  6.5  8.0  9.2  10.0
```

That is I want the closer values to change more drastically than the far values. Is there an interpolation method available in pandas that can do it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply some transformations to the data. Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, None, None, 4, None, None, None, 10]])
df = df.fillna(np.nan)
df = 10**df
df = df.transpose().interpolate()
df = np.log10(df)
```

You can play with the powers to get something that matches what you need.